# jQueryUI tabs to accordion in Mobile browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs, jquery-ui-accordion

I have searched and tried many jQuery based libraries out there for Responsive tabs (tabs convert to accordion when viewed in device browsers), but no libraries are helpful with my content structure.
I have already tried following libraries but in vain:

```
Easy Responsive Tabs
jQuery Responsive Tabs plugin
jQuery Responsive Tabs github
```

My efforts so far are in the following fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/DHTTWL/8g1x5358/

The tabs are working fine in desktop browser, but I want to make them convert to accordion in device browsers, no other (tab to accordion) libraries are working (although if you make it work please share your answers), so show me how to do it using jQuery ui tabs itself.

Comment: Press ctrl L insert hyperlink  for the url and paste url there

Comment: @Mahadevan Done, can you check now ?

Comment: How about having separate tab n accordion widgets and  simply doing show/hide according to screen size..?